# Serialize SOAP message with explicit namespace specification

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, .net-core

I have some pretty basic svcutil auto generated classes.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class YoRequest
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="urn:something:important", Order=0)]
    public YoInner YoInner;

    public YoRequest()
    {
    }

    public YoRequest(YoInner YoInner)
    {
        this.YoInner = YoInner;
    }
}

 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="urn:something:important")]
public partial class YoInner
{

    private YoClass contactField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public YoClass Contact
    {
        get
        {
            return this.contactField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.contactField = value;
        }
    }
}

 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:something:important")]
public partial class YoClass
{

    private string accountIdField;
    // a bunch more fields here 

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public string AccountId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.accountIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.accountIdField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using WCF clients but it seems under Kestrel this blocks all incoming requests until this one operation is done. Further, on Linux performance is quite pathetic. On the contrary, sending normal HTTP requests is very fast.

So my idea was to serialize this to SOAP myself and just send to the external service.

However, i can't for the life of me figure this one out.

Given an instance like so:

```
var instance = new YoRequest
        {
            YoInner = new YoInner
            {
                Contact = new YoClass
                {
                    AccountId = "1234"
                }
            }
        };
```

I need to get the following XML (and the external service is very particular, it doesn't accept inline xmlns, i need to provide this exact value)

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:urn="urn:something:important" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header/>
  <env:Body>
    <urn:YoInner>
      <Contact>
        <AccountId>1234</AccountId>
      </Contact>
    </urn:YoInner>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I have hundreds of auto generated classes like `YoRequest`. I can't modify attributes on them.

I can get the XML like so

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Envelope xmlns:urn="urn:something:important" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Header />
  <Body d2p1:type="YoRequest" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <YoInner xmlns="">
      <Contact>
        <AccountId>1234</AccountId>
      </Contact>
    </YoInner>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

using the following code:

```
 public class Header { }
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class SoapE
    {
        [XmlElement("Header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Body")]
        public object Body { get; set; }
    }

        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("urn", "urn:something:important");
        XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SoapE), new []{typeof(YoRequest)});
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var env = new SoapE { Body = instance, Header = new Header() };

        mySerializer.Serialize(ms, env, ns);

        var stuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
       //now stuff contains the string i show above
```

However, this is not quite what i want :/

Answer (score 0):

Use the msdn tool xsd.exe the auto generate soap header must be from the schema URL at top of your xml produces the following classes.  You have to add your custom classes by putting them in either anyField or anyAttrField (note : these are arrays).

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.33440.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Envelope {

    private Header headerField;

    private Body bodyField;

    private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

    private System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] anyAttrField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public Header Header {
        get {
            return this.headerField;
        }
        set {
            this.headerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Body Body {
        get {
            return this.bodyField;
        }
        set {
            this.bodyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
        get {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr {
        get {
            return this.anyAttrField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyAttrField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Header {

    private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

    private System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] anyAttrField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
        get {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr {
        get {
            return this.anyAttrField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyAttrField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public partial class detail {

    private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

    private System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] anyAttrField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
        get {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr {
        get {
            return this.anyAttrField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyAttrField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Body {

    private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

    private System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] anyAttrField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any {
        get {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr {
        get {
            return this.anyAttrField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyAttrField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Fault {

    private System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName faultcodeField;

    private string faultstringField;

    private string faultactorField;

    private detail detailField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName faultcode {
        get {
            return this.faultcodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.faultcodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string faultstring {
        get {
            return this.faultstringField;
        }
        set {
            this.faultstringField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType="anyURI")]
    public string faultactor {
        get {
            return this.faultactorField;
        }
        set {
            this.faultactorField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public detail detail {
        get {
            return this.detailField;
        }
        set {
            this.detailField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would i `You have to add your custom classes by putting them in either anyField or anyAttrField (note : these are arrays).`?

Comment: The easy was is to to replace type in SOAP definition From : System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField To : MyClass[] myClass

Comment: That didn't work: `InvalidOperationException: Cannot serialize member of type YoRequest: XmlAnyElement can only be used with classes of type XmlNode or a type deriving from XmlNode`

Comment: Remove the square brackets defining XmlAnyElement.  Xml Serialization makes a class an element.